# Table not generating properly when text in the column is long

Tags: tables

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Simulation of the proposed Trust Evaluation process}
\label{table:SimulationTrustEvaluation}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering \arraybackslash} X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {>{\setlength\hsize{.14\hsize}}R >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C >{\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}C}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{User first commits a malicious activity and then plans to do a day-long authorized activity} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{User first do day-long authorized activity and then plan to commit malicious activities} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{User starts by random (whether to commit a malicious activity or do the day-long authorized activity)} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13}
Type of users & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD \tabularnewline
\midrule
User with direct trust & 2 & 9 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 68 & 287 & 8977 & 4 & 65 & 37 & 954 \tabularnewline
User with indirect trust & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 53 & 44 & 1368 & 4 & 44 & 12 & 326 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: why are you making each column so thin ? `\setlength\hsize{.07\hsize}}`  fiorces the column to be only 7% of the width that tabularx would make it by default.. Please provide a test file that shows the problem, not just a fragment.

Comment: In order to improve the output, allow linebreaks inside of the quite lenghty texts inside the three multicolumns.

Comment: There are too many columns here. So, length of each columns is such thin. I cannot upload a file here...

Comment: Your values of `>{\setlength\hsize{.14\hsize}}` don`t add up to the right value. Since you use a total of 13 columns, the coefficients you use should also add up to 13.

Comment: linebreaks are not working here...

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. How to make sure the table fits onto the page depends on how much space is available on your page. See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: No you are specifying  _the entire table_ is just a fraction of the available width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't set `\hsize` for the 13 individual columns, but only for the header cells that span 4 columns.

Why `>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep\relax}C`, you may ask, as the width of the 4-column header cells? Because the available width consists of `4\hsize` *plus* the three inter-column spaces, which each amount to `2\tabcolsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx,rotating,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep\relax}C}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Simulation of the proposed Trust Evaluation process\strut}
\label{table:SimulationTrustEvaluation}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {@{} L *{12}{C} @{}}
\toprule
Type of users & 
\multicolumn{4}{F}{User first commits a malicious activity and then plans to do a day-long authorized activity} & 
\multicolumn{4}{F}{User first does day-long authorized activity and then plan to commit malicious activities} & 
\multicolumn{4}{F}{User starts at random (whether to commit a malicious activity or do the day-long authorized activity)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
 & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{F} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} 
\cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13}
 & 
MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & 
MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & 
MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD \\
\midrule
Direct trust & 2 & 9 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 68 & 287 & 8977 & 4 & 65 & 37 & 954 \\
\addlinespace
Indirect trust & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 53 & 44 & 1368 & 4 & 44 & 12 & 326 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest one of the following two versions:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylength}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Simulation of the proposed Trust Evaluation process}
\label{table:SimulationTrustEvaluation}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4\mylength+6\tabcolsep}}
\setlength{\mylength}{\widthof{MPMA}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {R *{12}{wc{\mylength}}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{Y}{User first commits a malicious activity and then plans to do a day-long authorized activity} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{Y}{User first do day-long authorized activity and then plan to commit malicious activities} 
      & \multicolumn{4}{Y}{User starts by random (whether to commit a malicious activity or do the day-long authorized activity)}
       \\
\cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13}
Type of users & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD \\
\midrule
User with direct trust & 2 & 9 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 68 & 287 & 8977 & 4 & 65 & 37 & 954 \\
\addlinespace
User with indirect trust & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 53 & 44 & 1368 & 4 & 44 & 12 & 326 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Simulation of the proposed Trust Evaluation process}
\label{table:SimulationTrustEvaluation}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
\setlength{\mylength}{\widthof{MPMA}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {R *{12}{wc{\mylength}}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{malicious -- authorized} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{authorized -- malicious} 
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{random}
       \\
\cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13}
Type of users & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD & MPMA & CD \\
\midrule
User with direct trust & 2 & 9 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 68 & 287 & 8977 & 4 & 65 & 37 & 954 \\
\addlinespace
User with indirect trust & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 53 & 44 & 1368 & 4 & 44 & 12 & 326 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\small malicious -- authorized = User first commits a malicious activity and then plans to do a day-long authorized activity}\\
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\small authorized -- malicious = User first do day-long authorized activity and then plan to commit malicious activities}\\
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\small random = User starts by random (whether to commit a malicious activity or do the day-long authorized activity)}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the *usable* width of the header cells be `4\mylength+6\tabcolsep` rather than `4\mylength+8\tabcolsep`?

Comment: +1 for suggesting a drastic simplification of the header cells.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your feedback as well as for drawing my attention towards the incorrect usable width of the header cells. I corrected my answer accordingly.